# Going to Debian..... (2 questions)

Tags: boot, debian, multi-boot

So, I am going to Debian from [BOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharat_Operating_System_Solutions)(Linux), and I have 2 questions.

1. if i could be able to use the same HDD in both of the Operating Systems
2. If I would be able to Remove Debian, and use BOSS Linux only by using the software GRUB CUSTOMIZER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and Yes
1. Both Operating Systems can be installed in the same HDD by installing them in two partitions.
2. If BOSSLinux is your Primary OS install it first and then install debian and configure GRUB. When Removing Debian Remove the Entry for Debian in GRUB.cfg and format the partition where Debian was installed

Comment: please answer this one http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100755/bring-debian-to-second-position-in-the-grub-menu-at-startup